@Html.LabelFor "for" attribute not being correctly assigned - Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>
I am using ASP.NET MVC v5.2.3. I am getting the warning in Edge debugger tools:

Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>

The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field. It gives this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label
It sounds like my label's For attribute should be populated with the ID of the form element that this label is associated with but I am not sure how to accomplish this in the following code.
Here's my simplified model:
public class Index
{
    [DisplayName("Coverage Year")]
    public int CoverageYear { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CoverageYears { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
}

And the simplified view:
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoverageYear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CoverageYear, Model.CoverageYears, new { id = "ddlCoverageYear", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

This is the HTML that it produces:
<div id="initiateModalCoverageYearDiv" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="SelectedYearValue">Coverage Year</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="initiateModalVendorId_ddlCoverageYear" class="form-control" name="SelectedYearValue">
            <option value="2024">2024</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2023">2023</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

How do I modify the View to presumably generate the following such that the attribute is updated with the ID of the dropdown, initiateModalVendorId_ddlCoverageYear?
<label class="control-label col-md-3" 
       for="initiateModalVendorId_ddlCoverageYear">Coverage Year</label>


This did it.
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedYearValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @for = "initiateModalVendorId_ddlCoverageYear" })


This would require you to assign an ID to every element. Wouldn't there be a more convenient method?
